# How to use ng-if to test if a variable is defined

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to use `ng-if` to test if a variable is defined, not just if it's truthy?

In the example below ([live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/jKPN0dOHDWBtPxJHXv2R?p=preview)), the HTML displays a shipping cost for the red item only, because `item.shipping` is both defined and nonzero. I'd like to also display a cost for the blue item (shipping defined but zero), but not for the green item (shipping not defined).

JavaScript:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
      {
        color: 'red',
        shipping: 2,
      },
      {
        color: 'blue',
        shipping: 0,
      },
      {
        color: 'green',
      }
    ];
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat='item in items'>
    <li ng-if='item.color'>The color is {{item.color}}</li>
    <li ng-if='item.shipping'>The shipping cost is {{item.shipping}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

I tried doing `ng-if='angular.isDefined(item.shipping)'`, but it didn't work. Nor did `ng-if='typeof(item.shipping) !== undefined'`.

Comment: Use `ng-if="isShippingDefined(item)"`, and add the `isShippingDefined` function to the scope in your controller.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Try this:

```
item.shipping!==undefined
```

Comment: actually, should be `typeof(item.shipping)!==undefined`

Comment: actually if you are using typeof, it returns a string so: `typeof(item.shipping)!=="undefined"`

Answer (score 15):

I edited your plunker to include ABOS's solution.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat='item in items'>
      <li ng-if='item.color'>The color is {{item.color}}</li>
      <li ng-if='item.shipping !== undefined'>The shipping cost is {{item.shipping}}</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
```

[plunkerFork](http://plnkr.co/edit/IkRUVV4ihdbtzzR7dCih?p=preview)

Comment: Also, in a slightly different scenario, if you are looking to check if a variable is not defined but want to print something if it is undefined (like an error message for example), then use http://plnkr.co/edit/Td1KoRrPZ3LERsPh

Answer (score 4):

You can still use **angular.isDefined()**

You just need to set

```
$rootScope.angular = angular;
```

in the "run" phase.

See update plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/h4ET5dJt3e12MUAXy1mS?p=preview

Comment: Plunkr link not found