# Trigger ng-show after ajax data loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

Here is my code:

```
<div ng-show="!uaCtrl.hideAddNewSubCategory || uaCtrl.subCategories[2] == null">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Write new sub category name">      
</div>
```

**uaCtrl.subCategories** is a dynamic data comes from ajax call. I want to show input if **uaCtrl.subCategories** is **null**, else show data. But when I open my page, I see firstly input, then input disappear, then I see the data. How can I prevent to see input before data loaded?

Comment: Use ng-show on input - ng-show="!uaCtrl.hideAddNewSubCategory || uaCtrl.subCategories[2] == null">

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-hide="uaCtrl.hideAddNewSubCategory || typeof uaCtrl.subCategories === 'undefined'">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Write new sub category name">      
</div>
```

Comment: It gives error. here is error: Syntax Error: Token 'uaCtrl' is an unexpected token at column 40 of the expression [uaCtrl.hideAddNewSubCategory || typeof uaCtrl.subCategories === 'undefined'] starting at [uaCtrl.subCategories === 'undefined].

Comment: ok, try `typeof(uaCtrl.subCategories) === 'undefined'`. If that's also not available in Angular expressions see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25694310/how-to-use-ng-if-to-test-if-a-variable-is-defined

Comment: I write ng-show="!uaCtrl.hideAddNewSubCategory || uaCtrl.subCategories[2] === null" and it worked. I had to use triple = with null. Thanks for help.